# IBM MobileFirst Foundation 8.0 POST resource request in javascript is not working

Tags: javascript, post, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I have a problem in in MobileFirst Foundation 8.0 where the parameter in a POST request is not captured in the adapter, but in a GET request the  parameter is working fine.

**Example for GET request**

```
var url = "/adapters/samplePOST/unprotected/";
var resourceRequest = new WLResourceRequest(url, WLResourceRequest.GET);
resourceRequest.setQueryParameter("params","['value1','value2']");
resourceRequest.send().then(function(e){console.log(e)}, function(e){console.log(e)});
```

**Adapter side**

```
function unprotected(user){
    return {
        result:JSON.stringify(user)
    };
}
```

**Output**

> {\"result\":\"\"sd\"\",\"isSuccessful\":true}

**Example for POST request**

**client side**

```
var url = "/adapters/samplePOST/unprotected/";
var resourceRequest = new WLResourceRequest(url, WLResourceRequest.POST);
var data={"params": "['sd','ds']"};
resourceRequest.sendFormParameters(data);
resourceRequest.send().then(function(e){console.log(e)}, function(e){console.log(e)});
```

**Adapter side**

```
function unprotected(user){
    return {
        result:JSON.stringify(user)
    };
}
```

**Output**

> {\"isSuccessful\":true}

In POST request adapter side, the parameter is `undefined`.

Also, in my development console -> swagger, if I hit POST Request form query `[{"params": "['sd','ds']"}]` its working fine but from a cordova application the parameter can't be parsed but in same cordova application GET Request working fine.

Comment: What if you try queryparameters in your POST call? Is that working fine?

Comment: `.setQueryParameter` is meant for GET requests. With POST that will give "unsupported media type". I believe the @deena117 may have stumbled a defect here...

Comment: You are sending your request twice. Once with the form body, and once with no body.

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** note that you should change how you're making the request to the following:

```
resourceRequest.sendFormParameters(data).then(
    function(e) {
        console.log(e)
    },
    function(e){
        console.log(e)
    }
 );
```

`sendFormParameters` actually sends the request, so no need to also use `send`. Otherwise, you're sending the parameter - twice, which triggers this issue.

---

I've tried it myself and it is strange.
In Swagger I indeed get the following as the response body for a POST request as you've demonstrated:

```
{
  "result": "\"value1\"",
  "isSuccessful": true
}
```

But in the application the `result` property is missing from the response object.

Printing the `param` value in the adapter using `MFP.Logger.info` I can see the following **two** logger lines in the application server's **messages.log** file, even though I had only a **single** logger line:

> [10/9/16 10:57:00:643 IDT] 00000ec7 MFP.Logger                                                   I ********** the param value is: sd
>   [10/9/16 10:57:00:646 IDT] 00000f3e MFP.Logger                                                   I ********** the param value is: undefined

One with the value and another without... I suppose the undefined one is returned to the client, which is why you get no result value(?).

Comment: Do you have a working example with Angular? Just can't get it to work.

Comment: @Idan Adar is it possible to write log to file in server using Javascript adapter

Answer (score 2):

the problem is you mis-used the sendFormParameters() API .
use the (asynchronous promise) JavaScript API correctly.
in your examples use either sendFormParamters() or send() but not both API. these two functions are different ways to achieve same goal.

For example:

```
var resourceRequest = new WLResourceRequest(url, WLResourceRequest.POST);
var data={"params": "['value1', 'value2']"};
var result = resourceRequest.sendFormParameters(data).then(
                function(response){
                    alert ("responseText: " + response.responseText + " ** responseJSON: " + JSON.stringify(response.responseJSON));
                },
                function(err){
                    alert (JSON.stringify(err));
                }
);
```

the later API seems to work with no issues.

A PMR is being opened for the send() API.
when using MFP v8.0 Resource request with POST and empty body : content type must be set to application/x-www-form-urlencoded
if combined with the send() API.
The Android code will fail  (iOS works fine).
simple workaround: when writing the WLResourceRequest manually add an HTTP "Content-Type" header like this:

```
var resourceRequest = new WLResourceRequest(url, WLResourceRequest.POST);
    resourceRequest.setQueryParameter("params", "['value1', 'value2']");
    resourceRequest.setHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    resourceRequest.send().then....more code here...
```